# A topological proof of that $\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Suppose $F:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$ s.t. $F(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)dx$, and the open sets are assumed to be open intervals (and $2$ open-closed intervals in $[0,1]$). Is there a topological proof of that $F$ is continuous? The inverse of $F$ is the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$, how does it make sense to map an open interval in $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ by $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: Since you say that the inverse is $\frac{d}{dx}$, I suspect that you are referring to the mapping $f \mapsto F(f) (a) = \int^a_{-\infty} f(x) dx$?

Comment: @ArcticChar This is a question I came up with when I was doing my probability exercise. I was actually assuming $F$ being a distribution function. So I think the map should be $f \mapsto F(f) (a) = \int^a_{-\infty} f(x) dx$?

Answer (score 1):

What is $F(b) -F(a)$ for $a<b$? Can you get that small by choosing $b$ close to $a$?